# order of studying languages to make it easier

Tags: vocabulary

If I want to study more languages, what is the best order?

EG I know that if I study Spanish, learning Italian would be easier then.

I was considering more, Spanish, Italian, French, Russian, Tagalog, I was thinking about Chinese, Japanese, Turkish, Arabic. These.. if I spoke four, five languages I think that it would make me a better person.

I was thinking about making a selection from those, then arrange them in an appropriate order.

Comment: This question is incredibly broad. You seem to be asking about the intricate relationship between at least 9 languages, and asking which one(s) are easier, if you already speak 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 other languages? I don't think there's actually any possible way to answer this. Can you focus on a specific question you have right now?  Perhaps "As a speaker of English and Spanish, which of these languages will be easiest for me to pick up?"

Comment: @Flimzy Here is a question similar to the one you formulated: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/how-to-choose-an-easy-language-to-learn-based-on-the-languages-that-i-already-sp

Comment: @michau: I didn't formulate that question, but thanks for the link. I'll close this one as a duplicate to that.